# Error while installing AMD graphic drivers

Tags: 14.04, fglrx, 14.10, amd-processor

I have just started using ubuntu and while installing amd graphics ended up with this error- `Please install the required pre-requisites before proceeding with AMD Catalyst installation. Please check file usr/share/ati/fglrx-install.log for more details.`
Well I cant locate this fglrx-install.log file and also cant remove this error.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Paste the following into a terminal

sudo nano /etc/share/ati/fglrx-install.log

Then install every package in the list by typing

sudo apt-get install (package-name)

Use the command for every individual package. If you are running 14.04 or 14.10 make sure to install using "Generate Distribution Specific Package" rather than "Install on X.org" because the driver isn't compatible with the newest version of X.org.

Comment: This command `sudo nano /etc/share/ati/fglrx-install.log `  gives me an empty list and has no package in it??

Answer (score 0):

I think this are all the packages that AMD drivers need.
Install pre-requisites:
sudo apt-get install gcc gobject-introspection intltool libgirepository1.0-dev cmake execstack dh-modaliases debhelper dkms lib32gcc1

Comment: I did as you told but still the same error

Answer (score 0):

Since you have all the installation packages and there's nothing else to try then force the installation. This is unsafe, but I personally (as a user of amd's shitty Linux drivers) recommend doing this. cd into the installation folder, then type sudo ./amd...(just press tab it will complete the name) and them add --force
This is a real method of installing which the installer allows you to do.